# Can you run Odata without using API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, odata

Here I am using Blazor WebAssembly with pre-rendering, so to display people I use two services one for client side the other server side with the same interface.
On the client side it works well with Odata.
Here is the client-side implementation of PersonService:

```
public async Task<ODataServiceResult<PersonDto>> GetPeopleAsync(string filter = default(string), int? top = default(int?), int? skip = default(int?), string orderby = default(string), string expand = default(string), string select = default(string), bool? count = default(bool?))
{
    var uri = new Uri(http.BaseAddress, $"odata/Persons");
    uri = uri.GetODataUri(filter: filter, top: top, skip: skip, orderby: orderby, expand: expand, select: select, count: count);
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
    OnGetEmployees(httpRequestMessage);
    var response = await http.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
    return await response.ReadAsync<ODataServiceResult<PersonDto>>();
            
}
```

Server-side PersonController implementation:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IQueryable<PersonDto>>> Get()
{
    var people = context.Persons.ConvertToDto().AsQueryable();

    return Ok(people);
}
```

Now I would like to move the controller logistics to the server side service to do something like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IQueryable<PersonDto>>> Get()
{
    

    ODataServiceResult<PersonDto> oDataServiceResult = new ODataServiceResult<PersonDto>();
    persons.ODataQuery = Request.QueryString.Value;
    var oDataServiceResult1 = await persons.GetPeopleAsync();

    return Ok(oDataServiceResult1);
}
```

In the server-side service:

```
public async Task<ODataServiceResult<PersonDto>> GetPeopleAsync(string filter = default(string), int? top = default(int?), int? skip = default(int?), string orderby = default(string), string expand = default(string), string select = default(string), bool? count = default(bool?))
{
    if (ODataQuery == null) // if it is null the server side service that is injected.
    {
        var uri = new Uri(new Uri("https://localhost:7069"), $"test");
        ODataQuery = uri. GetODataUri(filter: filter, top: top, skip: skip, orderby: orderby, expand: expand, select: select, count: count).Query;
    }
            
    var people = context.Persons.ConvertToDto().AsQueryable();
    ODataServiceResult<PersonDto> result= new();
    result. Value = people;
    result. Count = context. People. Count();
    return result;
}
```

Obviously this implementation does not work!!!!
I have question how to make Odata work without going through the controller.
I found the beginning of a solution if I used
applyQueryOption. ApplyTo(people, oDataQuerySettings);
but if hard to implement, there is little documentation for Odata version 8 with net core 6.

Comment: Well, regarding your scenario and context you can have look at the [`official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/)

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron There is no information on this subject, maybe I missed